# $\arcsin(\omega \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2})$ isn't the same as $\arccos(\omega \cdot t)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing some basic level physics but I think I'm making an error in calculating something. I'm doing oscillations and if I have

$0.05 = 0.2 \cdot \sin(44.72 \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2})$ this should be the same as

$0.05 = 0.2 \cdot \cos(44.72 \cdot t)$

I have to calculate the time ($t$) and when using my calculator, from the formula using **cosine** the result I have is

$t = \frac{1}{44.72}\cdot \arccos{\frac{0.05}{0.2}}= 0.0294$

(**the calculator is set to radians because the arguments of the sine and cosine functions are measured in radians**).

However, when I used the **sine** formula I got

$\arcsin{\frac{0.05}{0.2} - \frac{\pi}{2}=44.72t}$

$t=-0.0294$

How is this possible? I get the absolute value albeit the sign is different. I don't know where I'm making a mistake since $\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos{x}$

Comment: If $f(x+a)=g(x)$ for invertible $f,\,g$ then $f^{-1}(x)-a=g^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: $\cos \omega t$ is also equal to $\sin (\pi/2 - \omega t)$ (or more possible $t$ values). This gives

$$t = \frac{\frac \pi2 - \arcsin \frac{0.05}{0.2}}\omega = 0.0294$$

Comment: In your question, simply taking $\arcsin$ gives a $t$ value such that $-\frac\pi2\le \left(\omega t + \frac\pi2\right)\le \frac\pi2$, and so $-\pi\le \omega t\le 0$. When instead considering $\sin (\pi/2 - \omega t)$, taking $\arcsin$ gives a different $t$ value such that $-\frac\pi2\le \left(\frac\pi2-\omega t\right)\le \frac\pi2$, and so $0\le \omega t\le \pi$.

Answer (score 3):

The main thing you need to realise is that equations such as these have infinitely many solutions.  The correct solution for your cosine equation is
$$t=\frac{1}{44.72}\Bigl(\pm\arccos\frac{0.05}{0.2}+2n\pi\Bigr)\ ,\quad n\in{\Bbb Z}$$
and for the sine equation
$$t=\frac{1}{44.72}\Bigl(\arcsin\frac{0.05}{0.2}+2m\pi-\frac\pi2\Bigr)
  \ \hbox{or}\ 
  t=\frac{1}{44.72}\Bigl(-\arcsin\frac{0.05}{0.2}+(2m+1)\pi-\frac\pi2\Bigr)\ .$$
These will actually give the same values for $t$, but the values of $m$ and $n$ may be different.  For example, the cosine result with $n=1$ and taking the $+$ sign gives
$$t=0.170$$
and this is the same as you get from the sine method, taking the second option and $m=1$.

To get a single definite answer you will need restrictions on the value of $t$, and this will come from the physics requirements, not from the mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question does not make sense. The functions $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ are defined on $[-1,1]$, so you must have good luck that $\omega \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2} \in [-1,1]$. For $t \ge 0$ this is never true (provided $\omega > 0$). Reading your question makes clear that the correct title should be

> $\arcsin(y) - \frac{\pi}{2}$  isn't the same as $\arccos(y)$

It seems that you used the fact that
$\sin(x+ \frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos(x)$ to conclude that the two equations
$$y =\sin(x+ \frac{\pi}{2}) \tag{1}$$
$$y = \cos(x) \tag{2}$$
which have solutions
$$x = \arcsin(y)-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$x = \arccos(y)$$
imply that
$$ \arcsin(y)-\frac{\pi}{2} = \arccos(y) .$$

In your question you consider the equations
$$0.05 = 0.2 \cdot \sin(44.72 \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2}) \tag{1a}$$
$$0.05 = 0.2 \cdot \cos(44.72 \cdot t) \tag{2a}$$
which must indeed have the same solutions $t$ because $\sin(x+ \frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos(x)$. But both equations have *infinitely many solutions*, thus having the same solutions means that the *set $\Sigma_1$ of solutions of $(1)$* agrees with the *set $\Sigma_2$ of solutions of $(2)$*. So if you have somehow determined solutions $t_1 \in \Sigma_1$ and $t_2\in \Sigma_2$, you cannot expect that $t_1 = t_2$.

Writing $x = 44.72 \cdot t$, the above equations are equivalent to
$$\frac{0.05}{0.2} = \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2}) \tag{1b}$$
$$\frac{0.05}{0.2} = \cos(x) \tag{2b}$$
Applying $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ produces
$$x = \arcsin(\frac{0.05}{0.2}) - \frac{\pi}{2} \tag{1c}$$
$$x = \arccos(\frac{0.05}{0.2})  \tag{2c}$$
This means $t_1 = \frac{1}{44.72} (\arcsin(\frac{0.05}{0.2}) - \frac{\pi}{2}) \in \Sigma_1$ and $t_2 = \frac{1}{44.72} \arccos(\frac{0.05}{0.2}) \in \Sigma_2$. But as we know, there is no reason to expect that $t_1 = t_2$.

The problem here is the naive use of the arcsine ands arccosine functions. Actually they have infinitely many *branches*, one for each closed interval of length $\pi$ on which $\sin$ and $\cos $ are bijective. For $\sin$ these are the intervals
$$J^s_k = [-\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi, \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi] \text{ with } k \in \mathbb Z$$
and for $\cos$
$$J^c_k = [k\pi, (k+1)\pi] \text{ with } k \in \mathbb Z .$$
Let us denote the inverse functions of $\sin : J^s_k \to [-1,1]$ and $\cos : J^c_k \to [-1,1]$ by
$$\arcsin_k : [-1,1] \to J^s_k$$
$$\arccos_k : [-1,1] \to J^c_k$$
You see that (1c) and (2c) should be written more precisely as
$$x = \arcsin_k(\frac{0.05}{0.2}) - \frac{\pi}{2}\in [(k-1)\pi,k\pi] \tag{1d}$$
$$x = \arccos_l(\frac{0.05}{0.2}) \in [l\pi, (l+1)\pi] \tag{2d}$$
This makes clear that the solutions $x$ depend on the choice of $k$ and $l$.

Your calculator takes the *[principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)* of the arcsine and the arccosine which are the functions $\arcsin_0$ and $\arccos_0$. But this **makes it impossible** that (1d) and (2d) produce the same value of $x$ because the function $\arcsin_0(x) - \frac{\pi}{2}$ takes values in $[-\pi,0]$ and $\arccos_0(x)$ in $[0,\pi]$.

If you are interested in the smallest positive solution for $x$ you must take $k=1$ and $l= 0$. Now observe that $\arcsin_1(y) = \pi - \arcsin_0(y)$. This shows that you must replace (2c) by
$$x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin_0(\frac{0.05}{0.2}) \tag{2c'}$$
if you want a consistent result.

*Remark.*

The equation
$$\arcsin_1(y) = \pi - \arcsin_0(y) \tag{*}$$
is intuitively obvious if we look at the graphs of these function branches. Here is a formal proof. For $y \in [-1,1]$ we have $\arcsin_1(y) \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$ and $\arcsin_0(y) \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Thus $\pi - \arcsin_0(y) \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$. Since $\sin$ maps $[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$ bijectively onto $[-1,1]$, (*) is equivalent to
$$\sin(\arcsin_1(y)) = \sin(\pi - \arcsin_0(y)) \tag{**} .$$
But this is true: The LHS gives $y$ and the RHS gives $\sin(\pi)\cos(\arcsin_0(y)) - \cos(\pi)\sin(\arcsin_0(y)) = 0 \cdot \cos(\arcsin_0(y))) - (-1)\cdot y =y$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are graphs, choosing the conventional branches (using $\omega = 1$)...

$\arcsin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$
[image: A]

$\arccos(t)$
[image: B]

Nope, not the same.  In particular, $\arcsin$ is increasing while $\arccos$ is decreasing.

Comment: The title is wrong.

Comment: I mean, the question is not stated correctly in the title.

Answer (score 0):

To get back to solutions in $t$ to the equation:

$t = \frac{1}{44.72}\cdot \arccos{\frac{0.05}{0.2}}$:

YES, $t= 0.0294$ will solve this, BUT ALSO, SO WILL $t=-.0294$. The $\arccos$ function on your calculator however, picked the *positive* value of $t$; i.e., the value of $t$ in $(0,\pi)$ satisfying $\cos t = \frac{.05}{.2}$ i.e., $t=0.0294$ instead of $t=-.0294$.

Likewise, your $\arcsin$ function on your calculator picked the $y \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ satisfying $\arcsin\Big(\frac{.05}{2}\Big)=y$ i.e., $y= -.0294+\pi/2$, which gives $t=-.0294$. With that said, $\pi-y$ $= .0294+\pi/2$ also satisfies $\sin(\pi-y) = \frac{.05}{2}$, and gives you your desired $t=.0294$.